# What are the risks not upgrading to 7?

Tags: 7, upgrading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drupal 6 end of life](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42382/drupal-6-end-of-life)

what are the risks if Drupal 8 comes out and Drupal 6 is not supported any more, but you will upgrade from 6 to 7 later ie 6 months after Drupal 8 has come out?

Thanks!

Comment: Oops just noticed, similar [question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42382/drupal-6-end-of-life) was here before.

Answer (score -1):

Only risk is that you will stop receiving updates(including security) once stable version of Drupal 8 is out. You can still keep running on Drupal 6 as long as security issues does not affect your sites. Drupal 6 will suffer same fate as [Drupal 5](http://drupal.org/node/3060/release?api_version%5B%5D=78) did.

> Release notes from last supported Drupal 5 release.
>
> The twenty-third maintenance and security release of the Drupal 5
>   series. Only fixes for security vulnerabilities and other bugs have
>   been committed. New features are only being added to the forthcoming
>   Drupal 7.0 release.
>
> This release fixes security vulnerabilities. Sites are urged to
>   upgrade immediately